# Role based authorization in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Can any one tell me how to implement roles based authorization in mvc3 for all the action methods.Till now in my application i have not written any code to track the user roles.

Only in the main menu of the application iam checking the roles to build the menu,but iwant to deny access to users when he types the url.I was thinking of implementing attributes.Can anyone give me suggestions .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Write your logic in OnAuthorization authorization filter and put into a base controller and inherit that base controller to each controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something below.

```
protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filter_context)
{
    #region If auth cookie is present
    if (auth_cookie != null)
    {
        #region IF loggedin user is a member
        if (SiteUsers.LoggedInUser.UserRole == UserRole.Buyer
            && filter_context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName == "Home"
            && filter_context.ActionDescriptor.ActionName == "Index")
        {
            filter_context.Result = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        #endregion

        #region If loggedin user is a super admin
        else if (SiteUsers.LoggedInUser.UserRole == UserRole.Administrator && !filter_context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Adminstrator), false).Any())
        {
            if (!filter_context.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AllowAdmin), false).Any())
            {
                filter_context.Result = RedirectToAction("Home", "Admin");
            }

        }
        #endregion

        ViewBag.SiteUsers = SiteUsers;
    }
    #endregion

    #region if authorization cookie is not present and the action method being called is not marked with the [SkipAuthentication] attribute
    else if (!filter_context.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SkipAuthentication), false).Any())
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) filter_context.Result = Json(new ActionOutput { Results = new List<string> { Url.Action("Signin", "Home") }, Status = ActionStatus.Error }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        else
            filter_context.Result = RedirectToAction("Signin", "Home");
    }
    #endregion

    #region if authorization cookie is not present and the action method being called is marked with the [SkipAuthentication] attribute
    else
    {
        SiteUsers = new ReplictivityUserDetails();
        ViewBag.SiteUsers = SiteUsers;
    }
    #endregion
}
```